# Looking for an efficient way to compute the variances of a multinomial distribution in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have an R matrix which dimensions are ~20,000,000 rows by 1,000 columns. The first column represents counts and the rest of the columns represent the probabilities of a multinomial distribution of these counts. So in other words, in each row the first column is *n* and the rest of the *k* columns are the probabilities of the *k* categories. Another point is that the matrix is sparse, meaning that in each row there are many columns with value of 0.

Here's a toy matrix I created:

```
mat=rbind(c(5,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1),c(2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0,0,0,0,0),c(22,0.4,0.6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),c(5,0.5,0.2,0,0.1,0.2,0,0,0,0,0),c(4,0.4,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0,0,0,0,0),c(10,0.6,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0,0,0,0,0))
```

What I'd like to do is obtain an empirical measure of the variance of the counts for each category. The natural thing that comes to mind is to obtain random draws and then compute the variances over them. Something like:

```
draws = apply(mat,1,function(x) rmultinom(samples,x[1],x[2:ncol(mat)]))
```

Where say `samples=100000`

Then I can run an `apply` over `draws` to compute the variances.

However, for my real data dimensions this will become prohibitive at least in terms of RAM. Is whether a more efficient solution in R to this problem?

Comment: The data table package would be useful to you. I'm not familiar with it enough to provide a solution, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is the variance of the counts, just compute it immediately instead of returning  the intermediate simulated draws.

```
draws = apply(mat,1,function(x) var(rmultinom(samples,x[1],x[2:ncol(mat)])))
```

Comment: Thanks. But I guess that if I also happen to be interested in other summary statistics like the mean than the draws must be saved?

Comment: You can return whatever you want from your function, you just have to program it. There's no reason you couldn't return a list containing both the means and variance covariance matrix.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how will computing the variance directly instead of saving the draws and then computing the variance save RAM. Is it not saving all the draws before computing their variance?

Comment: You do 100,000 samples *per row*, so it would use more ram to save out the full 100,000*20,000,000 samples then to just calculate your statistics one row at a time.